# Facebook post with Page long acces token doesn't display

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

Hello I'm facing a strange problem
I've succesfully get a Never Expire token with an app to post on facebook page it works well

[image]

But the probleme is no one see the post except me as admin :(
But if I use a one hour token , everyone can see the post :[image]

Did i miss something ? or some permission to enable ?

My app permission :

[image]

As user, i've the same permission as my app. So I don't think it's a permission problem. Maybe something some settings in the page or App ???
If someone have an idea, I would be glad to hear it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your App is not live. Go to the "Status & Review" tab of your App settings and flip the switch where it says "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?".

Comment: Thanks it was that :)